# Cordova InAppBrowser slower when hidden

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I noticed that when using Cordova InAppBrowser to load a page it takes much more to load when it's set to hidden=yes. What's happening?

Slow:

```
ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes,hidden=yes,clearsessioncache=yes');
```

Fast:

```
ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes,hidden=no,clearsessioncache=yes');
```

Editing the InAppBrowser.java i figured it out that the inappbrowser is essentially a webview in a dialog and that the setting "hidden=yes" launches hides the dialog. Why then the webview is much slower when the dialog is hidden?

Comment: What do you mean by webview in a dialog? Can you describe the context in which your calling the InAppBrowser?

Comment: i've looked at the source of inappbrowser plugin and studied it. it is a webview put in a dialog. so when set the inappbrowser hidden i'm basicly hiding the dialog. why if inappbrowser is hidden it is slower?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html#sample-show-help-pages-with-an-inappbrowser)

> We're setting the hidden property to yes so that we can show the browser only after the page content has loaded. That way, users don't see a blank browser while they wait for content to appear.

Analogously if you set hidden property to no browser will be shown as it loads.

Comment: But I do not want to show it. It just runs some javascript in web browser and returns me some arrays. The problem is that it works but it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I consider the best practice, hide the inappbrowser on first loading and put a loading screen while the page is loading, then show the hidden page when load is complete, but if you make it in all loading pages, the application performance will be more slow, because hide and show inappbrowser pages are too slow... by the way the best is show an image loading or text when the inappbrowser is loading with toast library. I modified a toast library to show an image with this purpouse: https://github.com/Ahiaz/toast_with_image.